# Android WebView not loading (probably) Javascript while browser does

Tags: javascript, android, wordpress, webview

I've run into a very unusual and probably noobish issue. There's this site on Wordpress and I've to show that in webview. It makes some checks on input of name and email and then the `Next` button shows the rest of the content (most probably JS but idk the exact implementation - too bad at web programming currently). It's working fine on the mobile browsers as well.

The issue is that the webview doesn't seem to perform any action on clicking the `Next` button. I've searched a number of SO questions and did several many trial and errors with the webview settings but to no avail.

Javascript is enabled on the webview, btw. Here's the link of the url, if someone wants to know (and tell me too, maybe) what exactly the issue is: http://www.stressandanxietymanagement.com/stress-test/

Maybe I'm missing something very basic. BTW please don't post the URL in the answers. I may have to remove the link once this issue is resolved.

Edit: logcats also show something related

```
11-05 03:50:56.319 19071-19071/innovation.stressmanagement I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1", source: http://www.stressandanxietymanagement.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1 (2)
11-05 03:52:00.619 19071-19071/innovation.stressmanagement I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(54)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of null", source: http://www.stressandanxietymanagement.com/wp-content/plugins/quiz-master-next/js/qmn_quiz.js?ver=4.6.1 (54)
11-05 03:52:11.849 19071-22147/innovation.stressmanagement W/chromium: [WARNING:keycode_converter.cc(91)] empty code string
11-05 03:52:12.396 19071-22147/innovation.stressmanagement W/chromium: [WARNING:keycode_converter.cc(91)] empty code string
11-05 03:52:16.612 19071-22147/innovation.stressmanagement W/chromium: [WARNING:keycode_converter.cc(91)] empty code string
11-05 03:52:21.136 19071-22147/innovation.stressmanagement W/chromium: [WARNING:keycode_converter.cc(91)] empty code string
11-05 03:52:23.873 19071-22147/innovation.stressmanagement W/chromium: [WARNING:keycode_converter.cc(91)] empty code string
11-05 03:52:26.920 19071-22147/innovation.stressmanagement W/chromium: [WARNING:keycode_converter.cc(91)] empty code string
11-05 03:52:27.983 19071-22147/innovation.stressmanagement W/chromium: [WARNING:keycode_converter.cc(91)] empty code string
11-05 03:52:27.988 19071-22147/innovation.stressmanagement W/chromium: [WARNING:keycode_converter.cc(91)] empty code string
11-05 03:52:29.597 19071-22147/innovation.stressmanagement W/chromium: [WARNING:keycode_converter.cc(91)] empty code string
11-05 03:52:30.528 19071-22147/innovation.stressmanagement W/chromium: [WARNING:keycode_converter.cc(91)] empty code string
11-05 03:52:32.503 19071-22147/innovation.stressmanagement W/chromium: [WARNING:keycode_converter.cc(91)] empty code string
11-05 03:52:46.558 19071-19071/innovation.stressmanagement I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(54)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of null", source: http://www.stressandanxietymanagement.com/wp-content/plugins/quiz-master-next/js/qmn_quiz.js?ver=4.6.1 (54)
```

The `Uncaught TypeError` is shown on clicking the `Next` button. The question, however, is how is it working fine on web browsers but not in webView?

***EDIT:***

I used this [Advanced WebView Library](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView) which worked fine. So, if anyone else is still having the similar issue, give that library (or any other alternative) a try.

However, I'd like to know why the built in `WebView` widget is not working fine.

Thanks

Comment: check logcat logs

Comment: @petey They don't seem to be giving any hint. Most of them are just `Surface`. `LibEGL` related but no error with any of the view is being shown.

Comment: One suggestion is to hook it up to Remote Chrome Debugging: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/ and see what the page does. You can also debug webviews https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Check if the JavaScript is written in ES5 or ES6. I have found that newer Android devices support ES6 while older ones do not.

Answer (score 1):

If webView is your WebView and you've already done with

> webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true) // Java

or

> webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true  // Kotlin

, please give it a try like below:

- Java

> webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

or

- Kotlin:

> webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true

- API reference:
  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings#setDomStorageEnabled(boolean)

In fact, "**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of null**" should be fixed by enabling DOM storage API with the above code line.

Hope it's helpful~

Answer (score 0):

when i get across this kind of problems a populate the code with some sort of visible debugg messages, like adding a div to the main dom, and auto numeric them so i know where the script stop.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit. I didn't get you much. 
The website is made by others. Moreover, I'm just acquainted with basic HTML and CSS. Can such a debugging be done with this much knowledge?

Comment: Since I cant see the javascript log I need tother kind of feedback, I put a div in a visible spot of the screen, then in the javascript I clean and appends numbers in a secuence. 

if you use jquery you can use something like $("#divId").empty().append("4")

Comment: Is that to be done in the app or in the website page? I'm sorry I'm too bad in this domain and the website has been coded by some other people which I don't have access to. I don't even know that kind of thing is possible in wordpress themes or not.

Answer (score 0):

Using webview should be straight forward. Try the following:

```
    wv = (WebView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // do whatever you want here once the page is loaded
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            // TODO: handle error in some way
        }

        @TargetApi(android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest req, WebResourceError err) {
            // manage however you want
        }
    });
    wv.loadUrl("http://www.stressandanxietymanagement.com/stress-test");
}
```

Comment: Did you get it to working? I had the same code as yours (with just custom webview client to override the urls). Also, I tried your code but still, nothing happens on clicking the `Next` button as working in the website.